# How to run Java Spring Boot project from Github in Ubuntu

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu

I'm a beginner in Java spring boot.
I have downloaded the Java spring boot project from https://github.com/xxpaypro/xxpay4pro.
But I don't know how to run this project.
I don't even know which version of jdk I have to install.
I am looking for experts who can help me from installation of jdk to full runing.
Help me!

I have installed Ubuntu and VS code.
Ubuntu version is ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64

Then I have downloaded project.

Which version of jdk do I have to install to this project?

Then, how can I run this project?
How can I deploy?

Thanks & Warm Regards

Comment: read the pom.xml, there you can find all the information you need. Rather, since it is a maven project, you could just run the maven goals clean install and it would probably build everything for you

Comment: sorry but what kind of answer you want? for basic installation you can google about it and you will find alot of install Instructions.

Comment: Sorry, but I don' know, really.

Comment: This isnt a help-me-from-start-to-finish site. If you have specific problems, you can ask a question, and someone would help. But you seem to not have any knowledge of the matter you need help with at all. If I was told today is your first time even touching the Java programming language, I would definitely agree. Is there any beginners guide/tutorials that you can do to get a better understanding of the subject matter BEFORE you try to deploy or start someone's complete project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which version of jdk do I have to install to this project?

Check [pom.xml](https://github.com/xxpaypro/xxpay4pro/blob/master/pom.xml#L39), there is java version for this project.

```
 <properties>
      <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
      <java.version>1.8</java.version>
      <spring-boot.version>2.1.7.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
      <fastjson.version>1.2.58</fastjson.version>
      <mysql.connector.java.version>5.1.34</mysql.connector.java.version>
      <dubbo.version>2.7.1</dubbo.version>
      <binarywang.version>3.6.0</binarywang.version>
      <projectRootDir>${basedir}</projectRootDir>
  </properties>
```

But if you new in Spring Boot you should read [Spring Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) first.

Comment: Thank you for your kind explanation. As you see in this project, there are many folders. How do I use?

Comment: Why you try run project which you don't know/understand? Try something simpler and read manual as I said before. Then you will try more complex project. Dude, small steps, small steps

Comment: You're a good person. To be honest, I don't know spring boot. But I have a project. Just now, I have to run this project, I can move on. Help me, please. Thanks